# How to reload a uitable when the row of a different uitable's row is selected

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to reload a `UITableView` when the row of a different `UITableView's` row is selected. One of the problems I'm having is that both the `UITableView's` are in the same view. I would like a selection in Table1 to change the `NSMutableArray` that's used to populate Table2. And then reload the table.

At the moment it works fine, but only when the app re-lauches (or the view is popped off the stack and then re-visited) and `viewWillAppear` is called again

Here's my code:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:NO];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES;
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    // getting an NSString
    selectedTableString = [prefs stringForKey:@"selectedTableString"];
    if ([selectedTableString isEqualToString:@"Italy"]) {
        jsonStringCountry = @"http://****/v1/public/cities?country=it";
    }
    else if ([selectedTableString isEqualToString:@"Spain"]) {
        jsonStringCountry = @"http://****/v1/public/cities?country=es";
    }
    else if ([selectedTableString isEqualToString:@"UK"]) {
        jsonStringCountry = @"http://****/v1/public/cities?country=uk";
    }
    else if ([selectedTableString isEqualToString:@"Brazil"]) {
        jsonStringCountry = @"http://****/v1/public/cities?country=br";
    }
    NSLog(@"from two t selectedTableString %@",selectedTableString);

    // Download the yoodeal JSON
    NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:jsonStringCountry] encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy|NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSLog(@"jsonStringCountry is %@", jsonStringCountry);
    NSMutableArray *itemsTMP = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Create parser for the yoodeal api
    SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *results = [parser objectWithString:jsonString error:nil];
    itemsTMP = [results objectForKey:@"results"];
    self.displayItems = [itemsTMP copy];
}
```

My `UITableView` methods:

```
- (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
- (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [displayItems count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    }

    // Get item from tableData
    NSDictionary *item = (NSDictionary *)[displayItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"name"];
    [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Asap-Bold" size: 14.0f]];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Set different tags for different tableviews and when you want to reload just get the instance for that tableview for that tag using method "viewwithtag:" and call "reloaddata" against that tableview. Hope it may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the delegate method of `UITablveView`. The method is:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

This methods gets called when you click on the row of `UITableView`. Use this in following manner:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if(tableView == Table1)
   {
        //do the changes in array you want to do.
        [table2 reloadData];
   }
   else
   {
        //do the changes in array you want to do.
        [table1 reloadData];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create outlet for the table view

```
 [self.yourTableView reloadData];
```

Comment: This can be a comment instead of answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `[tablename reloadData];` onclick.

When you are updating tableview contents, it will not refresh the view. You can only see changes once the view controller is reloaded.
For updating the table instantly you need to call the above code

Comment: Use this code when user taps on first table and then reloadtable for second table.

Comment: Please improve the quality of your post by explaining how/why this code solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a property of the UITableView called `secondTableView` and then use `[secondTableView reloadData]`.

Comment: thanks. where would I put that though? Since both table views are in the same view it doesn't work in viewWillAppear except when the app relaunches. I need it to occur when a row in table1 is selected. thanks for your help :)

Comment: `tableView` is the one name you shouldn't give the table. Doing so will generate the "Local declaration of `tableView` hides instance variable" warning in Xcode.

Comment: Create a property of the secondTable and in the didSelectRow delegate method, just after you alter the secondTableView array, you should call reloadData on that property